# Multiple photos upload via Cloudinary.DotNet

Tags: image, upload, photo, cloudinary

I have configured my CloudinaryService to upload JUST ONE photo on my cloud on cloudinary. But i have really great troubles with configuring this to make it work on multiple uploads. Please help me, here is my code for single upload:

```
        public async Task<string> UploadPictureAsync(IFormFile pictureFile, string fileName)
        {
            byte[] destinationData;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await pictureFile.CopyToAsync(ms);
                destinationData = ms.ToArray();
            }

            UploadResult uploadResult = null;

            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(destinationData))
            {
                ImageUploadParams uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
                {

                    Folder = "cars",
                    File = new FileDescription(fileName, ms), 
                    PublicId = "audizone"

                };

                uploadResult = this.cloudinaryUtility.Upload(uploadParams);
            }

            return uploadResult?.SecureUri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
       }

}


I change IFormFile pictureFile to List<IFormFile> pictureFiles, going on with foreach (file in pictureFiles)...the only thing this service is doing is just uploading 2 or 3 times the same picture(the first one of three or two)...just not uploading two or three different photos. 




 <form asp-action="Create" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" multiple
                           class="form-control text-primary text-center"
                           id="picture"
                           name="picture"
                           placeholder="Picture..." />

     <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-dark" style="border-bottom-left- 
     radius:25%;border-bottom-right-radius:25%" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully loop using this method:

```
public static void BulkUpload(List<string> filePaths, ResourceType resourceType = ResourceType.Image, string type = "upload")
        {           
            var cloudinary = GetCloudinary(); // Initializing Cloudinary

            foreach (var path in filePaths)
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
                var streamed = "streamed";

                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    ImageUploadParams uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(streamed, memoryStream)                      
                    };

                    ImageUploadResult uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);

                    if (uploadResult.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        Console.WriteLine("uploaded: " + uploadResult.PublicId);
                    else
                        Console.WriteLine("Failed: " + uploadResult.Error);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for help but ...i'm afraid i cant implement it to my code... in my <IActionResult>  Create (List<IFormFile> pictures) and the multiple photos come from <input type="file" multiple name="pictures"> ....i couldnt handle the List<string> filepaths... :(

Comment: But i made it work for myself...thank you thank you a lot...now i have to assign the urls to the object collection ...